# Comparing a range of tables in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 30 columns and rows with each cell having a zero or a 1.

```
m <- data.frame(matrix(0:1, ncol = 30, nrow = 30))
```

I would like to compare the first fifteen columns with the corresponding next fifteen columns such that if the values in the cells being compared is a 1, then the cell for the new column created will also have a one. Example

```
A B C D

0 1 1 0 

1 1 0 1 

0 1 0 1 

1 0 0 0
```

When comparing A with C and B with D, two new tables should be made,

```
E F

0 0

0 1

0 1

0 0
```

I would also like to remove the tables being compared after the comparison is done. I found examples comparing individual tables, but comparing a range of tables and storing those results in a new range of tables is what I can't seem to do. Kindly help.

Comment: @d.b and storing those results in 15 tables? d[,1:15] <- m[, 1:15] == 1 & m[, 16:30] == 1 ?

Comment: @d.b yes. That would be ideal. And if the values are both 1, then they should be stored as a 1 and if not, a zero in the new data frame.

Comment: @d.b column 1 should be compared with 16, column 2 with 17, column 3 with 18 and so on and so forth

Comment: `sapply(data.frame(m[, 1:15] == 1 & m[, 16:30] == 1), as.numeric)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a single statement, but I've split it up to make it clearer:

```
compare <- m[,1:15] * m[,16:30]
cbind(m,compare)
```